# When are the moments of the square root of a random variable less than the moments of a random variable?

Tags: random-variable, moments

Let $X$ be a non-negative real-valued random variable. Can one find conditions for when the moments of $\sqrt{X}$ are less or equal to the moments of $X$? A specific example would be the chi-square and chi distributions.

Assume the pdf of $X$ is a continuous function $f_X(x)$. Then the pdf of $\sqrt{X}$ is $ 2x f_{X}(x^2)$.

So is it possible to find conditions for the following to hold
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} x^n \left (2x f_X(x^2)\right) dx \le \int_{0}^{\infty} x^n  f_X(x) dx \quad \mbox{for all integer $n \ge 1$}$$

Comment: Any rv supported by $(1,\infty)$.

Comment: Letting $Y=\sqrt{X},$ you are asking when for all $n=1,2,3,\ldots,$ it holds that $E[Y^n]\le E[Y^{2n}].$ This leads to many varied examples, such as when $Y$ is the absolute value of a Cauchy variable $T$: all its (positive integral) moments are infinite. Consequently, given *any* random variable $Y$, let $X$ be the square of a mixture of $Y$ and $T.$